# TCP Socket connection between Azure workers being kept alive?

Tags: sockets, azure, tcp, cloud

I am trying to debug an issue in our cache cluster on azure's compute service. Every worker instance is a cache node and they all open tcp sockets to talk to each other. After a while they lose a member here and there which then reconnects after a while but the problem is when running under load I have 10GB of data in the cluster and a loss of a member triggers a re-balancing which is extremely costly. I've played with timeouts in my caching layer but nothing seems to help. So my more fundamental question is: Does Azure close sockets between worker instances after some time? I know it does between clients and the load balancer but i wasnt sure how it treats socket connections between role instances.

Any insight would be appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Is TCP keepalive turned on for your sockets?